# Rstudio-Manipulating data in a list

Tags: rstudio

for a school project, I have a data set that set as a list.file. when I access the data is appears as such, note:for this I am accessing the second pos in the list, I have about 200 pos in total:

malefiles[2]

[[1]]

version..1

1     n_points: 22

2                {

3  328.444 275.496

4  434.921 275.029

5  331.713 401.121

6  427.449 400.187

7  271.936 270.826

8  356.464 254.014

9  388.221 255.882

10 494.698 268.491

11 263.997 274.095

12 301.825 277.831

13 349.459 277.364

14 411.104 278.298

15 459.673 277.831

16 515.246 276.897

17  368.606 340.41

18  355.53 351.151

19 391.957 350.217

20 374.253 395.527

21 374.253 416.925

22 373.276 483.314

23  280.342 404.39

24 499.835 402.522

25               }

What I have been trying to do was pull the two numbers based on the line they are in  for all elements in the list but I don't know where to start. I have no experience with R, but my professor asked to have it in R. this is a AI project .

Answer (score 0):

edit:

Ok, you need the rows 3-24 of each element in a list. I've created a list with 4 elements, each of these with 30 rows:

```
set.seed(772017)

lapply(c(1:4), function(x) {
  paste(round(runif(30, min = 200, max = 900)), 
        round(runif(30, min = 200, max = 900)), sep = " ")
}
) -> a.list
```

I'd suggest you to use the `apply` functions, they are like loops in `R` but are usually faster. The inner function `sapply` extracts rows 3-24 of a given element in the list and returns a vector. The outer function `lapply` extracts each element in the list.

```
lapply(seq_along(a.list), function(x) {
  sapply(c(3:24), function(y){
    a.list[[x]][y]
})
}
)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the transformation you wish to do to the list? I am having a hard time understanding (a) the format of your original list, (b) the format you wish to transform this object to. Do you want to bring it into a `data.frame` for instance?

Comment: there project is to use 22 point of a picture to determine if the person is a male or female, the data files are .pts  of which there are about 5 files per person and each person has their own folder, now I got the data to get two list based on gender, but now I'm not sure what to actually do.  I believe that I need to get the value of line 3-24 for each person, using a loop to get all,

Comment: sorry, I'm new to stackover. (a) the list that I currently have I created using femaleData <- list.files(pattern = "w", recursive = TRUE) and femalefiles = lapply(femaleData, read.delim). which create a list of all the files in the folders and reads them (b) and that is exactly what I want to convert it to

Comment: Ok, so you want to get the lines 3-24 (rows) for each element of a given list?

Comment: yes and I fi used a for loop that would be able to get all the elements

Comment: to make it simpler I tried to remove the 1-2 and 25 rows so only the two values would be in the list but I ended up just erasing elements from the list and had to reload the data

Comment: @BrianP. Was it helpful?

Comment: what is the function[x] and function[y] actually doing? I can guess that it is the two values that im trying to get, but I just don't understand how its doing it or see it. and thank you for helping me

Comment: im not having any luck implementing the concept ^^. It returns an error stating that it ether couldn't find X or unknown character detected.